# MySQL - select avg of list but ignore max and min value

Tags: mysql, average

I have a list of values in my database.

```
k v
1 5000
1 100
1 120
1 3
2 5000
2 100
2 120
2 4
3 10000
3 120
3 100
3 4
4 10
4 120
4 110
4 5000
```

I want to calculate the average of each k but I need to ignore the highest and lowest value of v for each k. (to remove spikes)

```
select avg(v) from table where v > min(v) and v < max(v) group by k
```

results in an :

> "Invalid use of group function"

I was thinking that this is a quite common task but I wasn't able to find any ideas from the docs.

Thanks for any advise.

Comment: What's your PRIMARY KEY? And what should the desired result look like?

Comment: That is not how you should avoid spikes

Comment: And the way one should avoid spikes is?

Comment: For each `k` your sample shows two values of `v`. If you want to ignore the min and max values of v, you won't have anything left to calculate an average on. (Or maybe I don't understand what you are looking for, and you could show an expected result.)

Comment: Of course I have many more values in the database. I've changed the sample to make this clear

Comment: @MikeNathas check this one: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a8828d/1/0

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this without worrying about whether there are duplicate min and max values of `v` (assuming you only want to ignore one of each) is to take the average as `SUM(v)/COUNT(v)`, but subtracting the min and max values from the computation:

```
SELECT k, (SUM(v) - MAX(v) - MIN(v)) / (COUNT(v) - 2) AS average
FROM data
GROUP BY k
```

Output:

```
k   average
1   110
2   110
3   110
4   115
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vbFXDeyMfLyHyAdNDVvqVP/1)

Comment: average for each k

Comment: @MikeNathas Sorry - thanks for pointing that out, I had missed it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
select avg(v) , k 
from table 
group by k  
    having k <> min (v) and k<> max (v)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Link:** [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a8828d/1/0)

```
select t1.k, avg(t1.v) average
from numbers t1 left join (
  select k, min(v) minv, max(v) maxv
  from numbers 
  group by k
) t2 on t2.k = t1.k and t1.v in (t2.minv, t2.maxv)
where t2.k is null
group by t1.k
```

Answer (score 0):

First get the min and max `v` for each `k` and then `left join` the table to the results so to get the average of the non matching rows:

```
select
  t.k, avg(t.v) average
from tablename t left join (
  select k, min(v) minv, max(v) maxv
  from tablename
  group by k
) g on g.k = t.k and t.v in (g.minv, g.maxv)
where g.k is null
group by t.k
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sqfUq6aQL8NGtTTafbEG8C/0).
Results:

```
| k   | average |
| --- | ------- |
| 1   | 110     |
| 2   | 110     |
| 3   | 110     |
| 4   | 115     |
```